# UIImagePickerController and a small custom preview

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to use an `UIImagePickerController` non-modally, with a small square preview. However, I get a big black bar at the bottom of the preview, which I can't get rid of (see the screenshot). Why is it there, and how can I get rid of it?

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imagePickerVC = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePickerVC.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imagePickerVC.mediaTypes = @[ (NSString *)kUTTypeImage ];
    _imagePickerVC.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    _imagePickerVC.delegate = (id)self;
    _imagePickerVC.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    _imagePickerVC.allowsEditing = NO;
    _imagePickerVC.showsCameraControls = NO;
    _imagePickerVC.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

    CGRect previewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150);
    [_imagePickerVC.view setFrame:previewFrame];
    _imagePickerVC.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_imagePickerVC.view];
    [_imagePickerVC viewWillAppear:YES];
    [_imagePickerVC viewDidAppear:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misuse of UIImagePickerController. To make your own image-capture interface, simply use AVFoundation.

Comment: Here's the section in my book explaining how to do it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch30.html#_image_capture_with_av_foundation

Comment: Thank you. I suspected I'd have to use AVFoundation.